# DOM XSS in jQuery function

Tags: jquery, xss

I have following code in my page and our scanner keep showing it as DOM XSS

```js
         var hash= window.location.hash
         if ( hash == '' || hash == '#' || hash == undefined ) return false;
         var target = jQuery(hash);
          
       
         target = target.length ? target : jQuery('[name=' + hash.slice(1) +']');
```

But I do not think this is valid, as hash in jQuery(hash will start with # and will prevent from DOM XSS execution.

Can you please suggest any XSS vector for this?

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/177261/is-xss-possible-with-jquerylocation-hash

Comment: This cannot be answered, it can still be vulnerable or not, depending on what happens to `target` (and maybe `hash`) later.